# Compare HTMLElement with ElementRef

Tags: angular, typescript, casting, angular5, elementref

I am working in angular 5. I am invoking a function on `keyup` and passing an event to it. I also have another reference like this

```
@ViewChildren('list') list: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

I am trying to check their ids and based on that do something.

But I am getting an error as

> [ts] Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'HTMLAnchorElement'

Can someone tell me how to typecast and check their ids. Thanks. I am new to this.

```
handleEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
const tabKey = 9;
if (event.keyCode === tabKey && !event.shiftKey) {
  const el: HTMLElement = event.target as HTMLElement;

  if (el.id === <HTMLAnchorElement>this.list.first.nativeElement.id) {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you please provide your HTML code as well? i do not think its necessary to typecast it as HTMLAnchorElement.
if you provide id in your HTML for the relevant element, you should be able to access it like,  this.list.first.nativeElement.getAttribute('id') and do a standard string comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
if (el.id === this.list.first.nativeElement.id)
```

and should be able to compare!